# How i can resolve this deadlock condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock, synchronized

I was trying to produce a deadlock condition. I was able to produce this using below code.

```
class MyCode {

  public static Object lock1  = new Object();
  public static Object lock2  = new Object();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

    Thread t1 = new Thread(()-> {
      synchronized(lock1) {
        System.out.println("Took lock on object" + lock1);
        try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(Exception e) {}
        synchronized(lock2) {
          System.out.println("hello world 1....");      
        }
      }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(()-> {
      synchronized(lock2) {
          System.out.println("Took lock on object" + lock2);
        try { 
          Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(Exception e) {}
        synchronized(lock1) {
          System.out.println("hello world 2....");      
        }
      }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

My requirement is to execute the code using this 2 threads.

How can i achieve this? Is there any other way in Java i can do this using wait/notify method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of [CompletableFuture](https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture)? Maybe this would be a more appropriate solution than using threads?

Comment: Re, "my requirement is to execute the code..." Execute _what_ code? Your example contains code. You can execute it, and when you execute it, it does what it does (it deadlocks). You said, "I was trying to produce a deadlock." OK, Mission accomplished! What's the _problem?_

Comment: @Solomon During my interview, i told him I have read that it is not a good practice to take nested locks. (I have read it in some Java book).  So he ask me based on this example, how can you resolve this without nested locks.

Comment: Various ways: The simplest is to have one lock for all shared data in the whole application. Another is to have a single "lock manager" object that knows about a `Set` of lockable things, and which allows a thread to acquire any subset of the things in a single, atomic operation, but which only allows a thread to change its 'locked' subset by first releasing everything, and then asking for a different subset. OTOH, nested locks can work, but you must make sure that every developer (including future, new hires) understand _exactly_ what order the locks are to be acquired in.